# Android : How can i compare gesture with other gesture?

Tags: android

How can  i compare (verify) a gesture with other one?
I captured some gestures in sd card and i want to compare user drawed gesture with captured gestures

Comment: read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureLibrary.html

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First you have to import your gesture file from your sdcard:

```
adb devices #This will give you the connected devices
adb -s deviceNameGivenByThePreviousCommand pull /sdcard/gestures Desktop/
```

**2.** Follow this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGestures/article.html) !